# Where to store email sent html text and their replies?

Tags: sql-server, database, email

We are working on a lead management system in which every email going out and their replies are stored in the SQL server database. Now the database size going above 90GB and the most of the size occupied by the table in which we are storing those email texts.
So, I'm looking for alternate ways to store these emails which are fast and efficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may consider partitioning of the table.

Comment: That will be costly for us as we are using SQL Server 2012 standard edition.

Comment: @JMKumawat have you checked compression methods, I just read about it somewhere, it considerably decreases size

Comment: @ARUN, yes that will certainly reduce the size. I will check this with our data.

Answer (score 0):

Data Compression can reduce the size

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh710070.aspx

It's for 2008 still can be useful for 2012
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894051(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can save emails in a XML files rather than to store on database,After saving use compression technique make a zip of that file and store at your project root code or anywhere else.